# ImportError: No module named mxTidy

Tags: python, tidy

I have installed egenix_mx_experimental-3.0.0-py2.7.But when I run the program, the error occured.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python/pyCharm/131113.py", line 21, in <module>
    from mx import Tidy
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mx\Tidy\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
   from Tidy import *
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mx\Tidy\Tidy.py", line 7, in <module>
   from mxTidy import *
ImportError: No module named mxTidy
```

I don't know what I am missing.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it's installed? Since you're working on Windows, one way to check is to see if there's a folder named "mxTidy" in any of your Python path:

```
from sys import path
```

Then run a code to check in the **listed path** and **all its subdirectories**, if any, if there's the "mxTidy" folder in there.

When you sort this issue then you can get back to inform us what the result was and then we'll know what to do next.